# Micronaut data jdbc: saving an existing entity creates a new entity instead of updating the existing one

Tags: jdbc, kotlin, micronaut

I have the following Kotlin code:

```
val book = bookRepository
        .findById(1)
        .orElseThrow { DoesNotExistException("Book with ID 1 does not exist") }

bookRepository.save(book)
```

I would expect that this code just saves the same entity again. However, it actually generates a new entity by copying all the fields and changing the ID.

The Entity itself is here:

```
@Entity
data class Book(@Id
                @GeneratedValue
                var id: Long?,
                val status: Book.Status
)
```

I am using `micronaut-data` (previously named `Micronaut Predator`) with JDBC, I am not using JPA.

How could I update the existing entity without creating a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how it works by design. From the documentation: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/snapshot/guide/#jdbcQuickStart, scroll down to "Updating an Instance (Update)" section:

> With Micronaut Data JDBC, you must manually implement an update method since the JDBC implementation doesn’t include any dirty checking or persistence session notion. So you have to define explicit update methods for updates in your repository.